# How to convert AWS CloudTrail JSON output time

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudtrail

Is it possible to convert the time output that is written inside the JSON data?
I tried searching inside the CloudTrail and SNS settings but didn't find any info about time output.

The Flow: AWS CloudTrail Insight → AWS CloudWatch Events → AWS SNS → Microsoft Teams

**Sample output**

"Account_ID": "", 
"Region": "ap-northeast-1",
"Event_Type": "AwsCloudTrailInsight",
"Time":  "2021-03-25T04:44:00Z", *(would like to change UTC into UTC +09:00 or to JST)*

I am thinking that connecting AWS SNS to Lambda and do the time convertion there but is there any much easier way?

Answer (score 0):

there's no built-in option to convert time in this case, you will need some compute in between:

`Amazon CloudWatch Events → ...Convert... → Microsoft Teams`

you can dispatch events to AWS Lambda directly instead of Amazon SNS:

`Amazon CloudWatch Events → AWS Lambda → Microsoft Teams`

if you are using Amazon SNS for different things, you can have multiple targets by replacing Amazon CloudWatch Events with Amazon EventBridge:

```
                                            / AWS Lambda → Microsoft Teams
AWS CloudTrail Insight → Amazon EventBridge  
                                            \ Amazon SNS → ...
```

Comment: Thank you vert much for your answer, I will try to edit my flow with AWS Lambda!